# The model is not being trained

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I created CNN for binary image classification:

```
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 124, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(15004, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), 2)
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), 2)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
```

Training:

```
num_epochs = 3
num_classes = 10
batch_size = 100
learning_rate = 0.01
model = Net()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
loss_list = []
acc_list = []

total_step = len(testset)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i in range(748):
        # Прямой запуск

        if i!=373:
            outputs = model(trainset[i*100 : (i+1)*100].float())
            c = target[i*100 : (i+1)*100]
            loss = criterion(torch.as_tensor(outputs), torch.as_tensor(c))
            loss_list.append(loss.item())
        else:
            outputs = model(trainset[i * 100: 37384].float())
            loss = criterion(torch.as_tensor(outputs), torch.as_tensor(target[i * 100: 37384]))
            loss_list.append(loss.item())
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if i!=373:
            label = labels[i*100 : (i+1)*100]
        else:
            label = labels[i * 100: 37384]
        # Отслеживание точности
        total = label.size(0)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        correct = (predicted == label).sum().item()
        acc_list.append(correct / total)

        if (i + 1) % 100 == 0:
            print('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.2f}%'
                  .format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, i + 1, total_step, loss.item(),
                          (correct / total) * 100))
    outputs = model(testset.float())
    total = labelstest.size(0)
    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
    correct = (predicted == labelstest).sum().item()
    print(correct / total)
```

And during training, accuracy for objects belonging to the first class is 100 percent, and for objects belonging to the second class 0 percent. Moreover, the situation does not change in the next epoch. What could be the problem?

Comment: It appears your model is always predicting objects to belong to class 0. This makes me think that your targets are all 0, and so the model is being trained to have this behavior. Have you debugged the targets to make sure that they're not all 0?

Comment: This line is also suspicious: `loss = criterion(torch.as_tensor(outputs), torch.as_tensor(target[i * 100: 37384]))`. On the first epoch, you're training on all of the data points. On the second epoch, you're training on all of the data points, *except* the first 100. And so on. Is this the intended behavior? If your data is not shuffled, then perhaps by the middle of training, all (or most) of the remaining training points belong to the same class.